# How to change the id of childlist views in nested listview in retool

Tags: listview, retool

I have nested listviews

parent listview: listview1
child listviews: listview2

Add component button is used to add a child listview at the bottom and the remove component is used to remove the listview from the bottom,
the same as Add button is used to add fields on the child listview at the bottom and remove the listview from the bottom.
when adding a child listview then every time name/id will be the same for every child list view.
please help me to change the unique id for every child list view.

[image]

gif demo
https://cdn.loom.com/sessions/thumbnails/d097acbbdb5045eab01a681e2aadb09c-00001.gif